# Is my Binary tree correct?

Tags: groovy, tree

I have been watching this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6lYob8STMI

And here is the code of it in groovy (just the add method):

```
    def addNode(k, v){
    def newNode = new MNode(key: k, value: v)

    if(!root){
        root = newNode
    }else{
        MNode currentNode = root
        MNode parent

        while(true){
            parent = currentNode
            if(k < currentNode.key) {
                currentNode = currentNode.leftNode
                if(!currentNode){
                    parent.leftNode = newNode
                    return
                }
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.rightNode
                if(!currentNode){
                    parent.rightNode = newNode
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is my version, my attempt of writing my binary tree after:

```
public void addNode(int val){
    println "Adding ${val}"
MNode node = new MNode(val);

if(root == null){
    root = node;
    return;
}else{
    MNode newParent = root
    while(true){
      if(node.value < newParent.value){
        if(newParent.leftNode == null){
            newParent.leftNode = node
            return;
        }else{
            newParent = newParent.leftNode
        }
      }else{
          if(newParent.rightNode == null){
              newParent.rightNode = node
              return;
          }else{
              newParent = newParent.rightNode
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Now these are the in/pre/order traversal functions from the video:

```
public void inOrderTraversal(MNode node){
    if(node) { //because of the children might be null
        inOrderTraversal(node.leftNode)
        println "MNode ${node.value}"
        inOrderTraversal(node.rightNode)
    }
}

public void preOrderTraversal(MNode node){
    if(node) { //because of the children might be null
        println "MNode ${node.value}"
        preOrderTraversal(node.leftNode)
        preOrderTraversal(node.rightNode)
    }
}

public void postOrderTraversal(MNode node){
    if(node) { //because of the children might be null
        postOrderTraversal(node.leftNode)
        postOrderTraversal(node.rightNode)
        println "MNode ${node.value}"
    }
}
```

They print exactly the same things when I run them on my tree, as they do on the tree from the video. Is that a good way of checking if my tree is correct?

Answer (score 2):

If your output matches the video, then I'd say you implemented a binary tree according to the instructions in the video. Whether that's correct or not I'm not sure because there are various binary tree variants.

Here's an implementation similar to that in the video. The difference is that it's Groovy-er. I think it's also easier to understand.

```
class BinaryTree {
    Node root

    BinaryTree add(Comparable key, String name) {
        def newNode = new Node(key: key, name: name)

        if(root == null) {
            root = newNode            
        } else {  
            addUsingIterator(new SearchIterator(search: key, node: root), newNode)            
        }

        return this
    }

    /*
     * Finds the parent Node for the specified Node.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key already exists.
     */
    private void addUsingIterator(Iterator iter, Node node) {
        // findAll() is a hack to use last()
        def parent = iter.findAll().last()

        switch(node <=> parent) {
            case -1:
                parent.left = node
                break
            case 0:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException('Duplicate keys not allowed.')
                break
            case 1:
                parent.right = node
                break
        }      
    }
}

class Node implements Comparable {
    Comparable key
    String name

    Node left
    Node right

    String toString() { "Node $key named $name" }

    int compareTo(Object other) { this.key <=> other.key }
}

/*
 * Traverses a BinaryTree to search for the specified
 * Comparable. Returns either the matching Node or the
 * parent under which the Comparable should be added/inserted.
 */
class SearchIterator implements Iterator<Node> {
    Node node
    Comparable search

    void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException() }

    boolean hasNext() {
        node != null
    }

    Node next() {
        def parent = node

        switch(search <=> node.key) {
            case -1:
                node = node.left
                break
            case 0:
                node = null
            case 1:
                node = node.right
                break
        }

        return parent
    }
}
```

When adding a Node, I'm using a custom Iterator to search for the parent of the new Node. This allows Java and Groovy to handle the iteration. A tree can be created like this:

```
def tree = new BinaryTree()
    .add(50, "Boss")
    .add(25, "Vice President")
    .add(15, "Office Manager")
    .add(30, "Secretary")
    .add(75, "Sales Manager")
    .add(85, "Salesman 1")
```

I also use an Iterator to implement traversal. Here's an implementation of PreOrder traversal:

```
/*
 * An Interator that traverses the BinaryTree in PreOrder
 */
class PreOrderIterator implements Iterator<Node> {
    def stack = []

    PreOrderIterator(Node root) {
        stack.push root
    }

    void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException() }

    boolean hasNext() {
        stack.size() > 0
    }

    Node next() {
        def parent = stack.last()

        stack.pop()
        if(parent.right) stack.push parent.right
        if(parent.left) stack.push parent.left

        return parent
    }
}
```

With the PreOrderIterator you can iterate through the tree and do what you please with each Node. For example, this is all it takes to print each Node in PreOrder:

```
new PreOrderIterator(tree.root).each { println it }
```

Finally, assertions to check the code:

```
assert tree.root.key == 50
assert tree.root.left.key == 25
assert tree.root.left.left.key == 15
assert tree.root.left.right.key == 30
assert tree.root.right.key == 75
assert tree.root.right.right.key == 85

def iter = new PreOrderIterator(tree.root)
assert iter.stack[0].key == 50

assert iter.next().key == 50
assert iter.stack[0].key == 75
assert iter.stack[1].key == 25

assert iter.next().key == 25
assert iter.stack[0].key == 75
assert iter.stack[1].key == 30
assert iter.stack[2].key == 15

assert iter.next().key == 15
assert iter.stack[0].key == 75
assert iter.stack[1].key == 30

assert iter.next().key == 30
assert iter.stack[0].key == 75

assert iter.next().key == 75
assert iter.stack[0].key == 85

assert iter.next().key == 85
assert iter.stack == []
```